# Amazon Cloudfront trackers, do they mean anything in an investigation?

Tags: spam, tracking, cloud-storage, domain

One way I use to find domains owned by the same people is through tracking codes (Google Analytics and such). Recently I've come across a domain with this tracker code:
d1lxhc4jvstzrp
When I lookup domains with this tracking code on VirusTotal I get almost 3 million matches.
The details section says this about the domain I am investigating:

Trackers

- Amazon Cloudfront
- d1lxhc4jvstzrp (https://d1lxhc4jvstzrp.cloudfront.net/themes/registrar/images/namecheap1.svg) 2022-07-22 10:18:09 UTC

Is it possible that the same person or company owns almost 3M domains or is it some way Cloudfront has of dividing their domains into groups or something?

When I looked up this tracker I found this:

https://publicwww.com/popular/cssdomains/index.html

https://publicwww.com/websites/%22d1lxhc4jvstzrp.cloudfront.net%22/

I suppose it doesn't mean much investigation wise, but I'm still curious about what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a CloudFlare expert, but I hope I can still share my thoughts here.

To begin with, let's clarify the first part:

> is it some way CloudFront has of dividing their domains into groups or something?

I would bet the answer is "**No**". Amazon [says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-returned.html) the following:

> You use the distribution's domain name in the links to your objects. For example, if your distribution's domain name is d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net, the link to /images/image.jpg would be https://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/images/image.jpg. You can't change the CloudFront domain name for your distribution. <...>
> **CloudFront domain names are unique**. Your distribution's domain name was never used for a previous distribution and will never be reused for another distribution in the future.

The next point is:

> Is it possible that the same person or company owns almost 3M domains?

Well, you know very well that from technical PoV this is very much possible - nothing prevents you from registering any number of domains. However, why would you say that someone *owns* the website by just having a *reference* to their resource from that website? Imagine you install Google Analytics on your website - to do that, you'll need to embed some JS file which will be downloaded from Google cloud, perform some operations, collect some data and send it back to Google cloud. Does that mean that Google now *owns* your website? Definitely not :)

So, I would say that we are probably dealing here with some organization that has web scripts or any other resources that are embedded into many, many (as you discovered, 3M+) domains.

Now, what this organization might be? That is not too easy to find out reliably (only AWS has the data and documents that can actually **prove** some relationship to a particular organization), but you can download any file from that domain and see what's inside it.

I took one random sample (a [file](http://d1lxhc4jvstzrp.cloudfront.net/scripts/js3caf.js) having a Hybrid Analysis [report](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/ea224fdd21c8c7d5b0bb389871eadf138ad2cfbef75dbcd7abe03ae3973f5c5b?environmentId=120)). It contains the following code:

```
var pageLoadedCallbackTriggered = false;
var fallbackTriggered = false;
var formerCalledArguments = false;

var pageOptions = {
    'pubId': 'dp-teaminternet01',
    'resultsPageBaseUrl': '//parkingcrew.net/?ts=',
    'fontFamily': 'arial',
    'optimizeTerms': true,
    'maxTermLength': 40,
    'adtest': true,
    'clicktrackUrl': '//track.parkingcrew.net/track.php?',
    'attributionText': 'Ads',
```

We can see that there is a reference to some "parkingcrew.net" domain here. By googling, you can find a reference to a [company](http://www.parkingcrew.net/) that is probably related to this.

There might be some other references to other companies in other files, but I don't think it's relevant to the question we are having here. I think we can assume with high confidence that this CloudFlare domain is related to some advertisement or marketing/tracking network that includes at least ParkingCrew trackers/ads.

Now, coming to the top question: **do they mean anything in an investigation?** My answer is: **they might, but not much anyway**. There are definitely cases when site owners discover references to ParkingCrew resources that they are not aware of ([one](https://serverfault.com/questions/638929/parkingcrew-net-hijacking-our-domain), [two](https://www.reddit.com/r/Domains/comments/f54k17/parking_domains_and_monetization_for_a_newbie/)). There are also [cases](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5ae6edc5f4bcd45d39249caa060611716191775a7a5e29d532f3a3aa8bfc43ac/behavior) of executable files connecting to this domain, likely in attempt to simulate user requests in order to get paid for the ads display. I would say that in the majority of cases the requests to ParkingCrew domains are probably benign, and the cases when they are unintended are most likely related to adware, not malware.

Comment: Could the high number of domain names mean that some kind of domain generating algorithm is used?  e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_generation_algorithm  Or possibly they are automating purchasing domains that have been searched for?

Comment: Which domain names are you referring to exactly? Those having Parking Crew trackers on them?

Comment: I guess the ones with "d1lxhc4jvstzrp" tracking code?  Or are those all affiliate-linked embeds?  Is it possible that all "parking" pages created by ParkingCrew have the embed to track traffic to the parked domains?  (service provided to their customers and not one particular client's affiliate link?)

Comment: Sorry, I still fail to get the question it seems. If you refer to a link from the original question (https://publicwww.com/websites/%22d1lxhc4jvstzrp.cloudfront.net%22/) - then the domain names listed there are definitely **not** DGA-produced, rather human-created. Now why and how they all are having Parking Crew tracker - that's a question I can't really answer reliably. My bet would be that it's mostly referral program, and domain name owners are willingly using Parking Crew services to generate some revenue. But that's just a bet. https://www.parkingcrew.com/faq.php?mode=detail&detail=27